# sum of consecutive arithmetic progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I was facing the following problem:

if $a, b, c$ are natural numbers in order and in a arithmetic progression with R=2, and $a^2 + b^2 - c^2$ = 0, what is $a+b+c$?

Comment: If you have an arithmetic progression with $R=2$, can you rewrite $b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A/Q $a=b-2$ and $c=b+2$. Then $a+b+c=3b$

As $a^2+b^2-c^2=0$ we have,

$b^2+4-4b+b^2-(b^2+4+4b)=0$

$b^2-8b=0$

$\Rightarrow b=8$(as $b\in N$)

So $a+b+c=3b=24$

Comment: not quite there yet ... another clue?

Comment: Now do you get it???? @philippe

Comment: $a+b+c=12$ is possible. Missed it?

Comment: How @Inceptio , I cant get you????

Comment: Even $3,4,5$ are in arithmetic progression.!

Comment: @Inceptio ,it is but with the common difference 1 whereas in the question the common difference given is 2.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Solve for $a\in\mathbb{N}$ the equation
$$a^2+(a+2)^2-(a+4)^2=0,$$
then $$a+b+c=3a+6.$$

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+b^2=c^2$

Pythagorean triplets. Only triplet group which are in arithmetic progression are $(3k,4k,5k)$

Therefore, $a=3k,b=4k,c=5k$ and $a+b+c=3b=12k$ .

Here $k=2$, therefore, $a+b+c=24$